# Wi-Fi doesn't connect

Tags: wireless

I'm an Ubuntu newbie.
I just installed 13.10 to a formatted notebook (clean installation).
When I try to connect to my wireless net it tries to connect but it doesn't work. The password is right and the signal is Good to Excellent. 
I just don't get it, how can I solve this?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked case? Even if you think it's one thing it might be the opposite. Try typing it with caps ON and OFF.

Comment: I did, I found out that is a wireless-adapter problem. I got a Broadcom 4313 which is kinda problematic. Hoping to find a solution soon. ^^'

Comment: Have you ensured that the broadcom driver is enabled in the additional drivers page?

Answer (score 0):

Please do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe brcmsmac
```

now your wireless should be working unless you have tried another driver besides the wl if it stops working after a reboot then do:

```
sudo su 
echo brcmsmac >> /etc/modules 
exit
```